# Getting "unknown custom element" warning in the console when I try to import Vuestrap

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am a newbie at Vue, and I try to import and use the VueStrap input component as in the first example [here](https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/#input).

This is how my component looks like (build-ui-x is under node_modules):

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="items-wrapper">
        <bs-input v-model="input"
                  label="Username"
                  help="Only allows lowercase letters and numbers."
                  error="Insert username"
                  placeholder="Username can't start with a number."
                  pattern="^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$"
                  :mask="mask"
                  minlength="5"
                  readonly
                  required
                  icon
        ></bs-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

  import * as BuiInput from 'build-ui-x/src/Input.vue';

  export default {
    name: 'buildPrimaryCard',
    data: function() {
      return {
        rdHeaderNames: ['SIN', 'Item', 'Rev'],
        input: ""
      }
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
      mask: function (value) {
        // change to lowercase, remove up to the first letter,
        // and then remove all other unsuported characters
        return value.toLowerCase().replace(/^[^a-z]+/,'').replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g,'');
      }
    },
    mounted () {

    },
    components: {
      BuiInput
    }
  }
</script>
```

build-ui-x is just a wrapper for vueStrap. Github link to the input component [here](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Input.vue).

The error I see on the console:

```
vue.esm.js?65d7:571 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <bs-input> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <BuildPrimaryCard> at D:\workspace\myReb\web\web-reb\src\components\build\BuildPrimaryCard.vue
       <Home> at D:\workspace\myReb\web\web-reb\src\components\build\Build.vue
         <App> at D:\workspace\myReb\web\web-reb\src\App.vue
           <Root>
```

And Build.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-three-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save as draft</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Output to PDF</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Issued</button>
    </div>


    <build-primary-card></build-primary-card>
    <build-model-card></build-model-card>
    <build-revision-history-card></build-revision-history-card>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import * as PrimaryCard from './BuildPrimaryCard.vue'
import * as ModelCard from './BuildModelCard.vue'
import * as RevisionHistoryCard from './BuildRevisionHistoryCard.vue'

export default {
  name: 'build',
  computed: {},
  methods: {},
  mounted () {},
  components: {
    'build-primary-card' : PrimaryCard,
    'build-model-card' : ModelCard,
    'build-revision-history-card' : RevisionHistoryCard
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to find the keyword "bs-input" in the Input.vue file, but there was nothing like it. There should be a reference like that, if I use it on my template right?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used VueStrap before but looking at the code you should import the input component like:

```
import bsInput from 'vue-strap/src/Input'
```

Add it to components

```
components: {
    BuiInput,
    bsInput
}
```